# How do I get the Twitter Widget to act as if any other element?

Tags: css, html

I have been attempting for days to fix an issue that I have been having with content, specifically text, but in general my content box, overflowing onto my Twitter Widget. The widget is seemingly being ignored as if it were non-existent and the text will overlap the widget when the browser gets too small. How could I fix this?

I'd like for the Twitter Widget and the 'Footer' to remain above and below each other (I will eventually move the 'footer' below the widget). As the browser is made smaller I would hope that the content-box with the paragraph and video in it would move close to the widget and 'footer' without overlapping them, nor forming underneath them. Just force the page to scroll. For reference you could look at any twitter feed.

I do not want this to happen: http://i.imgur.com/d79CvQL.png

Bare in mind that I am pretty new to this whole thing. I intend to be more of a backend developer, but know that I need to get well rounded in all aspects of development if I want to succeed in any career opportunity. And a big thank you to anyone and everyone who provides tips, tricks, and fixes! Also, sorry if this isn't the right format!

Here is a Jsfiddle of the markup as it is right now: http://jsfiddle.net/Codewow/8LeNV/

I'll be sure to keep backups of these files in case of future developers dealing with the same issue.

HTML Markup:

```
<body>
<div class=wrapper>
<div class=header>
<!-- Insert header image here via CSS-->
</div>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href=#>Home</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href=#>Server Rules</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href=#>News</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href=#>Forums</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href=#>PvP Stats</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href=#>MCF Thread</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href=/IRC.php>IRC</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id=content>
        <div id=footer>
            <div id="sidebar">
                <ul>
                    <li class="footer-item">&copy; 2010-2014 SyroCraft</li>
                    <li class="footer-item">Jobs</li>
                    <li class="footer-item">About</li>
                    <li class="footer-item">Help</li>
                    <li class="footer-item">Terms</li>
                    <li class="footer-item">Yada</li>
                    <li class="footer-item">Yada</li>
                    <li class="footer-item">Yada</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <p class=twitter><a class="twitter-timeline" height="485px" width="310px" href="https://twitter.com/SyroCraft" data-widget-id="335981577555308544">Tweets by @SyroCraft</a>

        </div>
        <script>
            ! function(d, s, id) {
                var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                    p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? 'http' : 'https';
                if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
                    js = d.createElement(s);
                    js.id = id;
                    js.src = p + "://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
                    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                }
            }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs");
        </script>
        </p>

    <div id=maincontent>
         <h3>SyroCraft Minecraft Server</h3>

<p>Here at SyroCraft, we strive to create and expand a dedicated and upstanding             community of builders, role-players, pvp-ers and socialize-ers. Our main focus is on community involvement. Whether it be an event or content for our website. We work together to create the best place to play and enjoy Minecraft. Click around a bit and check us out!    Watch our server trailer below!</p>
        <p id=video>
            <object>
                <param name="movie" value="//www.youtube.com/v/tNwfnvkDFB0?version=3&amp;hl=en_US"></param>
                <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
                <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
                <embed src="//www.youtube.com/v/tNwfnvkDFB0?version=3&amp;hl=en_US"      type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height=300 width=500 allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed>
            </object>
        </p>
        <!-- insert trailer here! -->
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS Markup:

```
.wrapper {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
height: 100%
}
/*body{
background: url(images/bg.png);
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover; 

}*/
html {
font-family: arial, sans-serif, times;
font-size: 1.1em;
background: #666666;
}
.header {
height: 100px;
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-bottom: -2px;
background-image:url(images/logo.jpg);
background-size: 700px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position:center;
background-color: #00dc00;
}
#IRC {
height: 95%;
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
nav {
margin: 0;
width: 100%;
background-color: #00d100;
}
nav ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
overflow: hidden;
text-align: center;
}
nav ul li {
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
width: 105px;
margin: -2px;
background-color: #05d100;
overflow: hidden;
}
nav a:link {
text-decoration: none;
color: #555555;
}
nav a:visited {
color: #99FF99;
}
nav li:hover {
background-color: #00FF00;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 769px) {
nav ul li {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: left;
}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
.header {
    display: block;
    background-image:url(images/mobilehead.png);
    background-size: 380px;
    background-position: top;
}
}
/*#twitter {
display: inline-block;
float: left;
position: static;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
width: 14%;
height: 500px;
padding: 60px;
border: dashed;
overflow: hidden;

}*/
#content {
display: inline-block;
position: static;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
width: 93%;
height: 650px;
padding: 60px;
border: dashed;
z-index: 1;
}
#footer {
border-radius: 5px;
float: left;
text-align: left;
height: 60px;
width: 310px;
background-color: #00dc00;
/*padding: 5px;*/
font-size: .8em;
z-index: 1;
margin-top: 50px;
}
#footer ul {
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-left: -35px;
text-decoration: none;
list-style-type: none;

}
.footer-item {
margin: 0 auto;
display: inline-block;
padding: 5px;
}
.twitter {
/*position: static;*/
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 30px;
float: left;
z-index: 0;
overflow: auto;
}
#siderbar {
display:inline;
padding:20px;
z-index: 0;
border: groove;
}
#maincontent {
float: none;
position: static;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 600px;
border: solid;
z-index: 3;
overflow: auto;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1377px) {
.sidebar {
display: block;
}
}
/*#right {
display: inline-block;
float: left;
position: static;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
width: 15%;
height: 500px;
padding: 60px;
border: dashed;
overflow: hidden;


}*/
p {
margin-bottom: 50px;
}
#video {
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Try using some client end framework like bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/ Your site code has serious issues.

Comment: Alright, I'll look into it. I've been messing with the code so much trying to fix my constant issues that it's really not up to my own standards, ha ha.

Comment: Yeah, the bootstrap helps a lot. Checkout the examples there is ready to go templates that you can use and those works in mobile too! One main thing is just to learn using the grid: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to all of this was simple, while Link13 answered the question as it was asked, it was not answered how I meant it to be.

I found out that by adding a min-width and max-width to the wrapper in CSS, it will lock the page to a certain size and force it to add the horizontal scrollbar.

See code:

```
.wrapper {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
height: 100%
max-height: 1092px;
min-height: 1020px;
}
```

This perfectly solved the problem I had with the content box moving over and underneath the info-box and behind the twitter widget.

Answer (score 1):

try marking the twitter feed as `position: absolute;` in order to prevent text overlapping.

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8LeNV/1/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Alright, that fixes the overlapping, but now the widget will overlap the text when the browser is too small. Would it be the same or similar steps to stop that from happening?